# Trigger to convert date from timezone to another one

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench, datatrigger

i want to create trigger to convert (s_start) value from (s_timezone) to (Africa/Cairo) Timezone and stored in new column (s_start_Cairo) for example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to capture the offset time between your two timezones. This is the query for that

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'Europe/London', 'Africa/Cairo')), '%H:%i') AS offset;
```

Then you can add this offset to your start time and save the value in the new column

Comment: but where s_start value in query